# Finding Variances and Covariances over multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have shipment data between origins and destinations over a 52 week period. I'm trying to
a) find the number of shipments between an origin and destination for each week 1 - 52 (done) 
b) Find the variance in weekly shipment numbers (see code) 
c) Find the autocorrelation in those weekly shipment numbers (need much help on)

Any ideas on how to do b) better, and how to do c) at all?

```
SELECT [Origin], [Destination],

    (SQUARE(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))+
    SQUARE(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))+
    SQUARE(SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    -
    3*
    SQUARE((SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    SUM(CASE WHEN [DeliveryWeek] = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/CONVERT(Decimal(10),3)))/2 as VARIANCE

FROM DATA
```

Many thanks!

Comment: For B, I dont know if this is what you're trying to get at, but SQL has a built-in VAR() function which calculates variance

Comment: Yep, but that calculates variances in a column, instead of across columns

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the result of step A to calculate step B? Something like;

```
select
    Origin,
    Destination
    var(ShipmentsPerWeek)
from
    a_data
group by
    Origin,
    Destination
```

Answer (score 0):

I used SQLFiddle to put together a few datasets, but I've done three things.  The first is a pivot that returns the Origin, Destination and one column for each week.  The second is the Origin, Destination and the variance across all DeliveryWeeks.  The last is the DeliveryWeek and variance across all Origin and Destinations.

[SQLFiddle for SQL 2008R2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f57f59/4)

```
--Pivot over Weeks
select Origin
, Destination
 , [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]
  , [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19] 
from (select Origin, Destination
,DeliveryWeek
from dbo.Shipments ) src
pivot (count(DeliveryWeek) for DeliveryWeek in (
  [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]
  , [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19] ) 
       )pvt

--Variance by Origin and Destination
select Origin
, Destination
, VAR(DeliveryCount) DeliveryVariance
from (
select Origin
, Destination
, DeliveryWeek
, COUNT(*) DeliveryCount
from dbo.Shipments
 group by Origin
, Destination
, DeliveryWeek
  ) x
 group by Origin
, Destination

--Variance by DeliveryWeek
select DeliveryWeek
, VAR(DeliveryCount) DeliveryVariance
from (
select Origin
, Destination
, DeliveryWeek
, COUNT(*) DeliveryCount
from dbo.Shipments
 group by Origin
, Destination
, DeliveryWeek
  ) x
 group by DeliveryWeek
```

Hopefully this illustrates how to use the VAR() and PIVOT() functions which should help you sift out what you're looking for.